# Dynamic VPN tunneling technologies

Tags: vpn, cisco, dynamic, tunnel

Ok, so I'm asking a more specific question this time. 
I'm writing a paper about Cisco's DMVPN and one of the tasks I have is to make the analysis of available network solutions which use dynamic VPN tunnels. Because the paper is about DMVPN, I have to compare those solutions to it. I know there are a lot of dynamic tunneling technologies but I'm looking for ones that can be compared to DMVPN. So the question is: are there any technologies which use dynamic VPN tunnels (not necessarily using crypto) that can be compared to DMVPN? What are those technologies?

Comment: I still think you need to refine your question. Asking about the dynamic nature of DMVPN via, " are there any technologies which use dynamic VPN tunnels?" is very broad and generic as any browser that support https creates a VPN tunnel "on-demand". I think that's not what you mean but I'm making the point that the question is very broad. If you wish to compare the multi-point nature of DMVPN then the only other technology I can think of that comes close is MPLS but that's not strictly layer 3 either.

Comment: It may be just me but I'm a bit confused on what you want. Are you looking for technologies that use DMVPN type techniques that you can compare to Cisco DMVPN or are you looking for usage examples for deploying DMVPN?